# Show that the sum of the squares of 2020 consecutive numbers can never be perfect square

Tags: number-theory

Show that the sum of the squares of 2020 consecutive numbers can never be perfect square

I understand that it is not perfect square if it is congruent with 2(mód 3)

Comment: Hint:  Better to check $\pmod 4$.

Comment: http://math.hashcode.ru/questions/71079/диофантовы-уравнения-суммы-последовательных-квадратов?страница=1&focusedAnswerId=71097#71097

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3270189/determine-the-remainder-of-999-998-997-dots003-002-001-13#comment6726341_3270189

Answer (score 1):

I shall prove by induction: my claim is that all numbers that are the sum of the squares of $2020$ consecutive numbers are of the form $4k+2$, which cannot be a perfect square.

The basis step is verified as $1^2+2^2+\cdots+2020^2=\frac{2020\cdot2021\cdot4041}{6} \equiv2\pmod 4$

If $(n+1)^2+(n+2)^2+\cdots(n+2020)^2\equiv2\pmod 4$, then

$$(n+2)^2+(n+3)^2+\cdots(n+2021)^2$$

$$\equiv ((n+1)^2+(n+2)^2+\cdots(n+2020)^2 +(n+2021)^2-(n+1)^2)\pmod4$$

$$\equiv(2+(2020)(2n+2022))\pmod4$$

$$\equiv2\pmod4$$

This proves the claim and the fact that the sum of $2020$ consecutive squares cannot be a perfect square.

Comment: Could you explain me why does the third, fourth and fifth line pass? please

Comment: @Letnikov I merely expressed the condition for $n+1$ in terms of the condition for $n$ and proved it as one normally does when proving by induction. It might be worth looking at Lulu's answer as it's much simpler than mine.

Answer (score 1):

A simple proof that all such numbers are $\equiv 2 \pmod 4$:

It is easy to see that any collection of evenly many consecutive numbers begins and ends with numbers of opposite parity and therefore contains equally many odd and even numbers.  Thus your collection contains $1010$ odd and $1010$ even numbers.  Of course the square of any even number is $0\pmod 4$ and the square of any odd number is $1\pmod 4$.  Thus your sum is $$1010\equiv 2 \pmod 4$$
and we are done.